# Append a list from Class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append a list by reading values using instances,

```
class Class_Name:
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.input = input
        self.mylist = []
        input.mylist.append(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    val1 = Class_Name("Value_1")
    val2 = Class_Name("Value_2")
print(mylist)
```

But it gives me error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mylist'
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I print `mylist` with values `['Value_1','Value_2']`?

Comment: your code is wrong. Try brushing the basics of OOPs using Python.

Comment: Don't you mean `self.mylist.append(input)`?  Your `print(mylist)` won't work either, try `print(val1.mylist)`.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `input.mylist.append(self)`? What's this? Shouldn't it be: `self.mylist.append(self)`

Comment: How many lists do you want?  Do you want a single list or one associated with each object?

Comment: @cdarke I want to append all the Values to a single list - mylist

Comment: @UbdusSamad I am exploring python, Just stated, what does it mean -`self.mylist.append(self)`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - that statement is probably an error.  `self` is a reference to the current object (`val1` or `val2`) which has an attribute of `mylist`.  We are calling a method (function) on `mylist` to append to it.  We are appending the current object (`self`) - which is not what you want.

Comment: Do you want `mylist` to be global or belong to `MyClass`?  What is the purpose of `MyClass`?

Comment: Please read more about OOP, just asking and for and getting answer to stuff won't help you learn much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a class variable to get variable shared across instances.
Use below code to get what you want.

```
class Class_Name:
    mylist = []
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.input = input
        Class_Name.mylist.append(input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    val1 = Class_Name("Value_1")
    val2 = Class_Name("Value_2")
print(Class_Name.mylist)
```

Comment: What is the difference of giving `mylist =[]` inside `def __init__` and outside of it?

Comment: __init__ is a constructor and constrained to object. If you want a variable `mylist` to have values from all objects/instances,you have to make it a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `extend` instead of `append` to add more entries to `mylist` in `__init__` and call `instance_name.mylist` in main to print list.

Something like this:

```
class Class_Name:
    def __init__(self, input1, input2):
        self.mylist = []
        self.mylist.extend([input1, input2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    val1 = Class_Name("Value_1", "Value_2")
    print(val1.mylist)

# ['Value_1', 'Value_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` parameter on your `__init__` is `Value_1` the first time the class is initialised, and `Value_2` the second. However, strings don't have the method `append` so when you assume `input` parameter is a list, it fails.